# CSS Margin Different on iPhone than Desktop and Browserstack

Tags: css

So I know there'll be inconsistencies between browsers and devices when it comes to specific CSS styles, but this one in particular is puzzling me.

I'm setting margin-right to 20px regularly, and in my media query I adjust it 30px. However, for some reason I'm getting no space between the image and the text to the right of it.

Here's how it shows on my phone (iPhone 12):

[image: image with text on the right with no space between the image and text]

Here's how it shows on Browserstack on the same model and iOS version:

[image: Browserstack view of an iPhone 12 Pro, there is space between the image and text]

and finally here it is on desktop:

[image]

So my question is: what could be accounting for the different handling of the margin on my iPhone? I don't know of any other way to be able to check what might be cancelling out that style.

Full CSS for this component:

```
.home-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.home-content {
  flex-grow: 0.6;
}

.intro-text-section {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  flex-grow: 0.6;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.bot {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: #000000;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  background-color: white;
  color: #000000;
  height: 265px;

  /* below is to vertically align */
  position: relative;
}

.icon-img {
  height: 235px;
  width: 235px;
  border-radius: 18px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.bot-description {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  display: inline;
  /* below is to vertically align */
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.bot-name {
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 8px; /* this is to override the Angular Material h3 setting */
}

.bot-actions {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.bot-button-link {
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 138px;
}

/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-width: 812px) {
  .bot {
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    height: 275px;

    /* below is to vertically align */
    position: relative;
  }

  .icon-img {
    height: 130px;
    width: 130px;
    border-radius: 18px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    padding-top: 10px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 320px) {
  .bot {
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    height: 365px;
  }

  .icon-img {
    height: 130px;
    width: 130px;
    border-radius: 18px;
    margin-right: 12px;
    padding-top: 10px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Could it be due to the `display: inline` of your description ? Have you tried using the flexbox `gap` property instead ?

Answer (score 0):

Created a `flex` implementation starting point for you:

```css
.bot {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
  border: solid 1px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.icon-img {
  flex: none;
  width: 235px;
  height: 235px;
  object-fit: contain;
  margin-right: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .icon-img {
    width: 130px;
    height: 130px;
  }
}

.bot-description {
  flex: auto;
  min-width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bot">
  <img src="https://rardk64.com/assets/timezonebot.jpg" class="icon-img" alt="">
  <div class="bot-description">Your html description is here</div>
</div>
```